# PHP Postcode match function

Tags: php

I am trying to create a function which when the user is recovering their password they need to enter the correct email and postcode associated with that account. I have got everything working fine except this postcode match function.

Function which checks the database for a match

```
function postcode_from_email($email, $postcode) {
    $email = sanitize($email);
    $postcode = sanitize($email);
    return (mysql_result(mysql_query("SELECT `postcode` FROM `users` WHERE `email` = '$email'"), 0) == 1) ? true : false;
}
```

PHP validation

```
if(postcode_from_email($email, $postcode) === false) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-danger center">Postcode match not found.</div>';
}
```

Please could someone help me with this and point out what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: is it correct `$postcode = sanitize($email);`?

Comment: No you are right, I missed that. it should be sanitize($postcode) not sanitize($email)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're matching your results on the email only. You need to change the WHERE statement to:

```
WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `postcode` = '$postcode'
```

You're also sanitizing the postcode as the email address.

Comment: Thank you for your help! It is really good to have a second pair of eyes in a situation like this. Got it working now!